# Failed to do full integer quantization using tflite converter from a saved model: ValueError: Failed to parse the model: pybind11::init():

Tags: python, quantization, nullptr, tensorflow-lite

I am using tflite converter and input generators to create an end to end quantized tflite file from a saved model.

Tensorflow version is 2.3, and I am running the following code:

```
input_shape=(int(dataDimension / inputDims), inputDims,1)
batch_input_shape= (1,) + input_shape
def representative_dataset_gen():

for i in range(110):
    image = Xtrain_[i].reshape(batch_input_shape)
    yield [image]

converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_saved_model('saved_model/my_model')
converter.optimizations = [tf.lite.Optimize.DEFAULT]

converter.representative_dataset = representative_dataset_gen
converter.target_spec.supported_ops = [tf.lite.OpsSet.TFLITE_BUILTINS_INT8]
converter.inference_input_type = tf.int8  
converter.inference_output_type = tf.int8  
tflite_quant_model = converter.convert()
tflite_file = "FGRNN_Q.tflite"
open(tflite_file, 'wb').write(tflite_quant_model)
```

and the error that I receive is:

`ValueError: Failed to parse the model: pybind11::init(): factory function returned nullptr`

Comment: Is it possible to share your model if it's not proprietary? The code looks fine, here are some related issues: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/35194#issuecomment-615911451 and looks like you've already commented here: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/39392

This might be occurring due to the fact that you're using RNNs/LSTMs/GRUs (it's a relatively newly supported feature, so it might not be thoroughly tested)